# Допустимо ли "со" или только "из"? "При выходе cо стеклянных дверей метро - направо"

Tags: предлоги

Наткнулся на один сайт, где в контактах был текст:

*При выходе из метро - направо. Со стеклянных дверей метро.*

Смутило "со".

Подскажите, пожалуйста, можно ли тут употреблять этот предлог или недопустимо?
Речь не о разговорном языке, а о более формальном.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильно смущаетесь, новый товарищ по мукам в ВМПС им. Тургенева!

Всё, что "со", должно иметь антоним "на", а "из" - "в". На Украину - с Украины, а некоторые, по уши погрязшие в политкорректности, вторгаются в Украину и сбегают из Украины.

Понятно, да? В дом - из дому (из дома), в окно - из окна, в школу - из школы,

однако

на фабрику - с фабрики, на крышу - с крыши, на фонарный столб - с фонарного столба.

Со стеклянных дверей метро можно и нужно стирать пыль и иные ненужности, но если мы входим в двери, то выходим из них.

Только вот кухня (буквальная, эпизод квартиры) позволяет себе оба предлога: на кухню, с кухни; в кухню, из кухни.

---

Лучший сайт по русскому языку вновь не даёт себя копировать; [цитирую](http://gramma.ru/RUS/?id=13.8):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо! Очень жаль, что редактор веб-сайта не обратил внимание на эту ошибку на таком видном месте.

Answer (score 1):

**Со** стеклянных дверей можно лишь сорвать то, что **на** них наклеено. *Выйти* же можно только **из** дверей, если входили **в** них или **в** другие двери. Всё это парные предлоги противоположных направлений действия (**в/из**, **на/с**). Можно пойти направо и **от** дверей, если **к** ним перед этим *подошли*.

Answer (score 0):

Дело не в предлоге. Фраза странная, Без контекста вообще непонятно, что она означает. 
Замена "Со" на из "Из" понимания не добавляет. Похоже, что писал человек, для которого русский - не самый родной. А без понимания смысла, говорить о правильности предлога фразы как-то даже и неуместно.

> Речь не о разговорном языке, а о более формальном.

Да тут и в разговорном жанре - проблема, более напоминает кривляние на публику.

Если речь о **выходе из дверей**, то надо не только изменить на ИЗ, но поменять всю фразу: "После выхода из метро – повернуть налево".

Кстати, если я правильно идентифицировал сайт, то там уже все поменяли.

> При выходе из стеклянных дверей метро повернуть направо, далее, пройдя
>   пять метров по подземному переходу, повернуть налево и подняться по
>   лестнице

http://www.mosgortrans.ru/routes/detail/full/iz-moskvy-v-doneck-s-avtostancii-krasnogvardeiskaja/
Это тоже небезупречно стилистически, но все-таки много лучше - и главное понятнее.
*Хотя удивляет еще и назойливое упоминание того, что двери "стеклянные". Во-первых, они не не совсем стеклянные (это особый состав), во-вторых, а что, есть другие?*

Ну а если бы речь том, что "направо от выхода из метро", - так товарищи вообще запутали всех.

> редактор веб-сайта не обратил внимание на эту ошибку

Сильно сомневаюсь, что на "веб-сайтах" сейчас держат в штате редакторов. 
Но мне тут интересно, как вообще могла подобная фраза возникнуть. 
Абсолютно чужд какой-то национальной предрасположенности, но это явно не украинизм. Там - да, путаются предлоги С и ИЗ, но формы "СО" нет вообще, есть ЗИ.

*На сайте Мосгортранса (по моей ссылке) есть фамилия перевозчика, но на неё ориентироваться нельзя - она интернациональна, да и писал текст скорее всего не он.*
Короче, для меня происхождение подобного текста - полная загадка.

@GalinaAvanesova

> Лучший сайт по русскому языку вновь не даёт себя копировать;

Из армии, но с флота; с завода, но из дома

Почему мы говорим так? Есть ли какие-нибудь правила употребления предлогов "из" и "с" в значении "прибытия откуда-то"?

В этом значении употребляются оба предлога, но предлог "из" имеет более узкое, конкретное значение, а предлог "с" - более общее. Сравните: из дома, из школы, из ресторана, но: с юга, с симпозиума (симпозиум, юг не ограничены рамками каких- либо стен, как дом, школа, ресторан).

Интересно, что и в английском языке есть сходное явление: предлог "at" употребляется для передачи нахождения кого-либо или чего-либо в пространстве, не ограниченном рамками стен, предлог "in" - при нахождении в ограниченном определенными рамками пространстве.

Видимо, в то время, когда у людей формировался язык, было очень важно передать, в каком пространстве вы находитесь, в открытом или закрытом. Кстати, это еще одна из причин внимательно изучать язык, языковые явления, которые позволяют пролить свет на скрытые от нас тысячелетиями мотивы поведения людей, условия их жизни, формирования, прогресса.

У предлога "с" есть еще одна функция: обозначать движение сверху вниз, т. е. как бы спуск с гор, а не простое возвращение откуда-нибудь, поэтому мы используем этот предлог в таких случаях: с Кавказа, с Памира.

Эти смысловые различия, имеющие исторические объяснения, в настоящее время в значительной мере потеряны. Они уступили место отношениям чисто грамматическим, формальным. Нет однозначного ответа, почему в одних случаях мы говорим и пишем "из": из Прибалтики, из командировки, из армии, а в других - "с": с Камчатки, с совещания, с флота.

При обозначении обратного по направленности движения, т. е. движения "туда", предлог "с" всегда корреспондирует с предлогом "на", предлог "из" с предлогом "в". Во всех случаях, когда мы приехали с юга, мы вернемся на юг, если приехали из Канады, вернемся в Канаду.

В просторечии предлоги "из" и "с" нередко путают, употребляя неверно. Нельзя говорить: вернулся со школы, с магазина, с армии (вместо из школы, из магазина, из армии). Это противоречит литературной норме.